# Cordova geolocation currentposition result varies

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm currently using Ionic Framework to build an android app.

On PC (Google Chrome), My `currentposition` is incorrect while when I build an apk and installed it in my Galaxy Tab 4 I'm getting an accurate `currentposition`

Anyone care to explain why this happens?

PC Specs
Windows 7
Google Chrome

Device Specs
Galaxy Tab 4
No Cellular Feature

Both use the same network to connect to the internet.

Comment: Is it giving you a totally different location? Or an error?

Comment: totally different location, its near but not that near to be categorize as accurate

Comment: [GPS is not reliable](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples/wiki/GPSisUnreliable.md) FROM [https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples/wiki](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

A PC won't have GPS, so you're probably using wifi for location, and your Galaxy Tab 4 does have a GPS/GLONASS receiver, (nothing to do with the cellular network,) so can be accurate.